# How to read API Payload value using Python script

Tags: python, api, payload

I have an application which is supposed to add a device. When I scan a particular device it's serial number is passed through payload section of API and it reaches the python script where I'll be executing this API.

The format of payload is as follows:

```
"payload" : {
        "path":"serial_number(eg. Ag145ghjj)"
        }
```

What I want to do is read the incoming payload value (Payload  in the body of the api) in my python script.
How can I store just the payload containing the serial number in some variable and use it later.

Please let me know the steps required for this and guide me through.